# Is this php function call vulnerable to eval injection?

Tags: php, eval

Given this piece of code:

```
$func = $_GET['func'];
$argument = $_GET['argument'];
if (function_exists($func) && strcasecmp($func, 'assert') !== 0) {
    $result = $func($argument);
    ....
```

Is it possible to inject malicious code (for example eval) other than standard php functions given `eval()` is not recognized as function ?

Thx

Comment: "Given this piece of code" - So did *you* write it? Is it just an excerpt? Because it whitelists just one function name → however `assert` is pretty much the same as `eval`.

Comment: no , I found this code and I am trying to undesrtand how much vulnerable it is.. function_exists returns false in case of eval and true in case of assert , therefore the double check

Comment: What could be passed into the $_GET variable?

Comment: everything, it comes form the user input, ex: $func="printf", $argument="hello world" -> "hello world" will be printed